# SVG Support in IE8+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, svg, raphael

SVG would make the user interface of one of our intranet applications much more useful. My main goal is to use vectorized graphics which can be updated via asynchronous js calls and some elements could handle click/d&d events.

I know that the implementations of gecko, safari and chrome are quiet good. Now the big question is, how good is the IE8 svg implementation? What needs to be taken into account to make an SVG ui work well with IE8 (and maybe ie9)?

Comment: See the [SVG Web](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) library from Google for adding SVG support to otherwise-not-so-good browsers.

Comment: @Phrgoz: the mentioned library is certainly interesting, will check it out. thank you for that helpful link! I was playing with raphael http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 (in beta right now) supports SVG.  You can [download it here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/home).

Comment: Danke. IE8 already supports SVG. My question is how well, resp. what do I need to avoid (IE8 implementation seems to behave quiet different compared to safari/gecko/chrome)?

Comment: as Phrogz points out in another comment, the library i have used (Raphaël) ist using VML in IE8 and therefore i got some "results" in IE8 (however, bad results).

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics):

> As of April 2010, Internet Explorer, up to and including IE8, the latest release, is the only current major browser not to provide native SVG support, although native support is partially available in Internet Explorer 9 Platform Preview: Current IE versions require a plug-in to render SVG content. There are a number of plug-ins available to assist including: [...]

So the answer is: IE8's support is non-existent (without a plug-in or [library](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/)).

I think you owe @MichaelSScherotter's answer an apology :)

Comment: Here a screenshot of a stock IE8 (Win7) displaying my first SVG tests: https://wunderlin.net/ie8-svg.png. Apologies to Mr. Schröder. I have used a library called Raphaël.

Comment: @Spliffster I see you use "raphael" in the URL on that link. Are you using the [Raphaël library](http://raphaeljs.com/)? If so, this abstracts support for IE using [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) instead of SVG. **Edit**: Ah, I see from your comment to the question that you are. This is why you think that IE8 has SVG support when it does not.

Comment: Yes I did use Raphaël from raphaeljs.com. VML, hmm.